# why is this a potential leak of an object?

Tags: objective-c, properties

Could someone please explain why I get the "potential leak of an object" warning here ? I don't get it. Thank you!

```
-(Code) drawTo:(ContextClass *) trg
{
  CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
  CGFloat values[4] = { getRed(colour),
                      getGreen(colour),
                      getBlue(colour), 1.0 };

  trg.storedColourRef = CGColorCreate(rgbColorspace, values);    

  CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorspace);

  return OK;
}
```

Is it because I store the object in trg.storedColourRef ? ... which is a property in a different class:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGColorRef storedColourRef;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's because you create Quartz color with `CGColorCreate()` and pass it to some external (?) object. Compiler could not find corresponding `CGColorRelease()` call that shall be used to destroy color object and therefore generates this warning.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation. what If I do release it in a dealloc method of the external class with CGColorRelease(storedColourRef); does it prevent the actual leak ?